# Unable to execute knife CLI

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, rvm, centos6, knife

Can anyone suggest a reason why I can't execute knife?

Here's my error when trying to execute knife:

```
# knife
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- chef/knife/core/subcommand_loader (LoadError)
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/chef-11.8.0/lib/chef/knife.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/chef-11.8.0/lib/chef/application/knife.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/gems/chef-11.8.0/bin/knife:23:in `<top (required)>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/knife:19:in `load'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/knife:19:in `<main>'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Some other helpful output:

```
# rvm list
rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.3-p327 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-1.9.3-p551 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

Another:

```
# rvm env
export PATH="/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-                                             p327/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-        p327@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/bin:$PATH"
export GEM_HOME='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327'
export GEM_PATH='/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-         p327:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p327@global'
export MY_RUBY_HOME='/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327'
export IRBRC='/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p327/.irbrc'
unset MAGLEV_HOME
unset RBXOPT
export RUBY_VERSION='ruby-1.9.3-p327'
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [ChefDK](https://downloads.chef.io/chefdk/). It is not recommended and supported to use `knife` with other Ruby environments. I think that it is especially not compatible with Ruby 1.x.

Comment: This is correct, we require 2.2 or newer at this point. ChefDK uses 2.3.1 on all platforms currently.